# How do we pass different value to another activity by selecting choice-based table row in a table

Tags: android

I have created a table containing dynamic table rows. Each table row contain 5 textview containing data's like region name ,regioncode ,target etc. I have implemented a table row OnclickListner,So a user can select the table row to view more specific data in another activity. The problem is each table row Contain must diffrent regionCode to be passed to another activity. How could we pass this to another activity.I tried using string array but it show null point exception.

This is my code

// IF BRANCHFLAG IS ZONAL

```
    else if(branchFlag.equals("Z"))
    {
        final List<NameValuePair> details = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchCode", branchCode));
        details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchFlag", branchFlag));
        details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("finYr",finyear));
        details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("month", month_number));
        Log.d("month_num", month_number);
        response = apc.postURL(RETRIEVE_BRANCH_MIS_DETAILS_LINK, details);
        Log.d("**************", RETRIEVE_BRANCH_MIS_DETAILS_LINK + details);
        Log.d("RETRIEVE_MainMis_DETAILS_LINK", response);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            errorflag = jsonObject.getString("errorFlag");
            errormsg = jsonObject.getString("errorMsg");
            if (errorflag.equals("N"))
            {
                // adding 4 data sections to the table row
                TextView label_product = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                label_product.setId(0);
                label_product.setText(" Region   ");
                label_product.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tr_head.addView(label_product);// add the column to the table row here


                TextView label_target = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                label_target.setId(0);// define id that must be unique
                label_target.setText("        Target "); // set the text for the header
                label_target.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
                label_target.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                label_target.setGravity(5); // set the padding (if required)
                //  label_target.setWidth(10);
                tr_head.addView(label_target); // add the column to the table row here

                TextView label_achievement = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                label_achievement.setId(0);
                label_achievement.setText("     Achievement");
                label_achievement.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                label_achievement.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                label_achievement.setGravity(5);
                //  label_achievement.setWidth(50);
                tr_head.addView(label_achievement);


                TextView label_shortfall = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                label_shortfall.setId(0);
                label_shortfall.setText("     Shortfall");
                label_shortfall.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                label_shortfall.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                label_shortfall.setGravity(5);
                //  label_achievement.setWidth(50);
                tr_head.addView(label_shortfall);


                TextView label_ranking = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                label_ranking.setId(0);
                label_ranking.setText("     Ranking  ");
                label_ranking.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                label_ranking.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                label_ranking.setGravity(5);
                tr_head.addView(label_ranking);

                //  add the table row the the main table layout that we fetched at the start
                tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                TextView[] textArray = new TextView[jsonArray.length()];
                TableRow[] tr_head1 = new TableRow[jsonArray.length()];

                try {
                    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);// set as you need

                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                                               {
                        JSONObject jsonobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // JSONObject productData = product.getJSONObject("Product");
                        // String productDescription = product.getString("achievementPer");
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");


                        incomeAmount = ((jsonobj.getString("AchievementSum")));
                        excShort = ((jsonobj.getString("excShort")));
                        String excShort1 = excShort.replace(",", ".");
                        Double excShort2 = Double.parseDouble(excShort1);
                        Log.d("excShort, replace ,", excShort1);
                        Log.d("excShort in point format,", excShort1);
                        targetAmount = ((jsonobj.getString("targetSum")));

                        //ADDED BY SOORAJ
                        Regions = ((jsonobj.getString("regionName")));


                        zoneName=((jsonobj.getString("zonalName")));
                        Log.d("achievementPer123", String.valueOf((((excShort)))));

                        //Create the tablerows
                        tr_head1[i] = new TableRow(MainMis.this);

                        tr_head1[i].setClickable(true);
                        tr_head1[i].setId(i + 1);
                        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                            tr_head1[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                        } else {
                            Resources resource = getApplicationContext().getResources();
                            tr_head1[i].setBackgroundColor(resource.getColor(R.color.white_overlay));

                        }
                        // tr_head1[i++].setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        tr_head1[i].setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));




                        // Here create the TextView dynamically
                        textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);

                                                    //Modified
```

//

```
                        textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                        textArray[i].setText("  " + Regions);
                        textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);


                        textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                        textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                        textArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(targetAmount));
                        textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        // textArray[i].setWidth(10);
                        textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        textArray[i].setGravity(5);
                        tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);


                        textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                        textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                        textArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(incomeAmount));
                        textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        // textArray[i].setWidth(10);
                        textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        textArray[i].setGravity(5);
                        tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);

                        textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                        textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                        textArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(excShort ));
                        if (excShort2 > 0) {
                            textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        } else {
                            textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        // textArray[i].setWidth(120);
                        textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        textArray[i].setGravity(5);
                        tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);

                        //ADDED BRANCH RANKING

                        textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                        textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                        textArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(Rgn_Ranking));
                        textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        // textArray[i].setWidth(10);
                        textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        textArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.BOTTOM);
                        tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);


                        tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (tr_head1.length > 0)
                        {


                            tl.addView(tr_head1[i], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                            length = String.valueOf(tr_head1.length);
                            Log.d("LENGTH OF ARRAY", String.valueOf(length));


                            //Make the table row onClickable

                            tr_head1[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    Intent a=new Intent(MainMis.this,RegionMIS.class);
                                    Bundle extras = a.getExtras();

                                    startActivity(a);
                                }
                            });





                        }


                    }

                    if ((i == 0)) {
                        Log.d("No rows to display **", "");
                        tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //Toast.makeText(MainMis.this, "No data to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("ERROR...", e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            } else {
                tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errormsgedit.setText(errormsg);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERROR...ERROR..", ex.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.. i created one more textview with its visiblity as GONE

```
                                                   textArray[i] = new TextView(MainMis.this);
                                                   textArray[i].setId(i + 111);
                                                   textArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(regionBrCode));
                                                   textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                                   // textArray[i].setWidth(10);
                                                   textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                                                   textArray[i].setGravity(5);
                                                   textArray[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                   tr_head1[i].addView(textArray[i]);
```

Then i added this in onClick listner of the table row

```
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    String t=String.valueOf(v.getId());
                                    Log.d("ROW CLICKED : ",t);
                                    // get the table clicked
                                    TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)tl.getChildAt(v.getId());
                                    TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(5);
                                    String result=sample.getText().toString();
                                    Log.d("RegionCode",result);

                                    Intent a=new Intent(MainMis.this,RegionMIS.class);
                                    a.putExtra("regionCode",result);


                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMis.this, RegionMIS.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_REGION_CODE", regionCode);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Bro.. for each row I would like to assign diffrent regionCode which i get from json object.. and i want to pass it to another class. The problem is I cannot find a way to declare it... and I tried ur code.. it crashes the app..

Comment: Where are you storing the regionCode which you're parsing from the JSON?

Comment: This app function in a way that when i click its MIS icon it shows zonal data of an company in table view to the Administrative head. In Zonal table I show the region as a row. There are many regions which is equal to no of rows .. now each region have a regionCode.. So if i click a particular row containing a region, a new page will be diplayed conatining MIS of that region... now the table will display branch's under that region... hope u understood the concept

Comment: What does this line do? Regions = ((jsonobj.getString("regionName")));

Comment: It gets the region Name from json to be displayed in textview of each table... if u r confused.. The regionCode is not displayed in textview..ok bro